# Change Span Class Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to print error message next to a particular element if its null.

I know to add

```
<div> tag
```

after that element and printing it. But I dont have editing access to that code.

So, I thought to change the span class of the label of that element which highlist as missing field.

My Page is like

```
 <td><span class="fl">Country</span></td>
 <td class="abcdef" style="...." id="Country">
 <select>
 <option></option>
 </select>
 ....
```

Now I want to change the spanc class "f1" to "requiredText". 
But the problem is many labels are surrounded by

```
  '<span clas="f1">' 
   and 
  '</span>'.
```

Is there any way I can identify the it with preceding element of ID Country and associate it?

Comment: which is the span that u wanna change the class?? only the one with country as text??

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a jQuery tag here. So If you want to do this withoud jQuery you can do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('Country')     // get the table cell with id="Country"
        .previousElementSibling        // get its previous sibling so the td with the span
        .children[0]                   // get the span you want
        .className = "requiredText";   // overwrite it's class name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.f1').addClass('myclass).removeClass('f1')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('td .f1').removeClass('f1').addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".f1").each(function(x, span) {
        var text = $(span).html();
        if(text == '')
             $(span).addClass('requiredText').removeClass('f1');
    });
```